# Pass id param from Datatable to controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

I want to pass the id param of clicked row button of my datatable to my controller (by url or by ajax, or something). I'm using url call to a method on my controller and it works, but I don't know how can be passed the id (in code **************) of the column. My datatable in js is:

```
    var T_festivos = <?php echo json_encode($T_festivos); ?>;
    if ( T_festivos !== null){
        var table = $('#T_festivos').DataTable( {
            language: {
                "url": "<?=trad($this,'IDIOMA_DATATABLES');?>"
            },
            data: T_festivos,
            paging: true,
            ordering: true,
            pageLength: 10,
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    "targets": 0,
                    "visible": false
                },
                {
                    "targets": -1,
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": "<center><a class='btn btn-danger' href='<?=base_url()?>index.php/mantenimiento/borrar_festivo/(**************)'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a></center>"
                }
            ],
            columns: [
                { title: "" },
                { title: "<?=trad($this,'FECHA');?>" },
                { title: "" },
            ]
        } );
    }
```

Comment: try changing : `data: T_festivos` with `data: {id: T_festivos}`  , and then inside controller fetch it using : `id`

Comment: and then how can I fetch it in controller? If I write data: {id: T_festivos} the table doesn't show any row. My $T_festivos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem writting the html code in the controller:

```
for ($i=0; $i< count( $festivos->filas); $i++){

            $T_festivos[$i][0] = $festivos->filas[$i]->fecha;
            $T_festivos[$i][1] = "<center><a class='btn btn-danger' href='" . base_url() .
                "index.php/mantenimiento/borrar_festivo/" . $festivos->filas[$i]->idFestivo .
                "' ><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a></center>";

        }
```